# Почему таймер неправильно работает

Tags: ajax, javascript

Всем привет, решил сделать чат на Ajax, и как было указано в примере надо было сделать такую функцию:

```
    function loadData(){
    $.post("chat_engine.php",{action:"loadData"}, function(text){
        $("#mess_list").html(text);
        setInterval(loadData(), 1000);
    });
}
```

Так вот, а я решил добавить функцию, что когда нажимаешь на ник то он добавляется  в специальное поле, но беда из-за того что обновления слишком частое, то при нажатии на ник, ничего не происходит, я решил исправить это немного изменив функцию:

```
    function loadData(){
    $.post("chat_engine.php",{action:"loadData"}, function(text){
        $("#mess_list").html(text);
        setInterval(loadData(), 10000);
    });
}
```

Т.е теперь обновляться будет не раз в секунду, а раз в 10 секунд, но после обновления страницы, функция всё равно вызывается раз в секунду. Как это исправить?

Comment: setInterval замените на setTimeout. У вас там не раз в секунду, а геометрическая прогрессия будет.

Comment: Не помогает, тот-же эффект. Не могу выделить текст т.к обновление раз в секунду.

Answer (score 3):

А почему-бы, если у Вас чат, сообщения не представить в виде списка (ul)? Новые соответственно через append добавлять в конец. Таким образом не нужно будет обновлять все полностью.

По вопросу о setInterval/setTimeout:

Как уже сказал Yura Ivanov, `setTimeout` здесь уместнее, так повторный запуск запроса на сервер должен проходит только по получению ответа, а не автоматически.

Также лучше хранить результат функции setTimeout в переменной, чтобы потом можно было выполнить `clearTimeout`.

Я накидал небольшой пример: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs8kM/11/. Функция `nextAnswer` соответствует Вашей функции `loadData`.